# Exception when code is run on Online Java compiler unlike on notepad

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have written the code to **print the minimum number of insertions required to make any string a palindrome** . The code **runs perfectly** when written on **notepad** and compiled through **cmd**. But it gives ***Exception*** when run at any **online java compiler**.
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;


class Solution
{
  public void disp(String s)
{
    int l=s.length();
    int pos=-1;
    for(int i=l-1;i>0;i--)
    {
        char b=s.charAt(i);
        char b1=s.charAt(i-1);
       if(b!=b1)
        {
            pos=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    String w=s.substring(0,pos);
    int l1=w.length();
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<l1;i++)
     {
       char b=w.charAt(i);
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
}
public class scanner_call
 {
   public static void main(String[] args)throws InterruptedException
      {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the one line string");
        String s=sc.next();
        Solution p1=new Solution();
        p1.disp(s);
      }
 }
```

The online compiler shows this exception.

```
Enter the one line string
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
at scanner_call.main(scanner_call.java:39)
```

Why this very program runs perfectly in notepad but raises Exception in online compilers? What should i do?

Comment: looks like there is no input available on `System.in`.

Comment: At least some online systems require you provide stdin before running the program. Perhaps you left it empty?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get an IDE or at least a proper editor.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your program requires **input detection**, but the online compiler you use might not have input capability.

Try this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

Put your Source Code into the `Source Code` tab

Put your input into the `STDIN` (fyi, I put "*asd*" in there and worked fine)

Then you should see some result, to change the input, change the STDIN

Comment: yaa its working fine in  `STDIN` but when executing the same exception is occuring. What is the solution? what is deficient in the code?